# How to display all the columns inside a table once at least one similarity has been found between 2 database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

1. Database_name1(Criteria) -> table_name(tenantCriteria) and inside I have the following columns 

   -username

   -firsrent

   -occupation

   -age

   -tenantgender

   -income

   -history

   -address

   -tenantsmk

   -tenantpet
2. Database_name2(Tenant) -> table_name(preference) and inside I have the following columns

   -username

   -firsrent

   -occupation

   -age

   -tenantgender

   -income

   -history

   -address

   -tenantsmk

   -tenantpet
   3.Database_name3(Ad) -> each table has the usernames name, hence table_name($username) and inside we have the following columns

   -adtype

   -roomtype

   -negotiable

   -price

   -include

   -title

   -address1

   -address2

   -postcode

   -city

   -province

   -image

   -description

   If the user that log in's is a tenant, and he wants to see all the property for sell, she click on the rentalmatch button and what that button is supposed to do is to check the similarities between the tenants preference table and go through all the tables in the Criteria database and return all the username from the Criteria database that have at least on similarity with the tenants preference. Once it returns all the usernames I want to go to database *(Ad) where the tables have the usernames name that we found before. We go inside that usernames table and show all the property that that user is selling.

so far this is what I have:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    $sql = "
            SELECT t.username
            FROM Criteria.tenantcriteria AS t
         JOIN Tenant.preference AS p
                        ON t.firstrent = p.firstrent OR t.occupation = p.occupation OR t.age = p.age
                            OR t.gender = p.gender OR t.income = p.income OR t.history = p.history
                            OR t.address = p.address OR t.smoker = p.smoker OR t.pet = p.pet  
                        WHERE p.username = $username";

                        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysql_error());










                    ?>
```

From here on out what should I do? Is the php good? if not what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

This will show all the properties in an HTML list, you could use a `<table>` instead.

```
echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $owner = $row['username'];
    echo "<li>Owner: $owner<ul>";
    $owner_query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Ad.$owner");
    while ($property = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owner_query)) {
        echo "<li><dl>";
        foreach ($property as $col => $val) {
             echo "<dt>$col</dt><dd>$val</dd>";
        }
        echo "</dl></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```